# How to design a "I like" and "I don't like" system?

Tags: php, database, database-design, doctrine-orm

I need to create a voting system.

Votes even if they are different, could apply to two entities (for the moment, but likely to don't change much).

The two entities are Article & Comment, however, comments can only be up-voted (much like SO works with answers & comments).

I though that to avoid DRY principle, I could use a Vote entity, and then add a relation table for both Article & Comment, but my "vote" are more like a "I like" and "I don't like" which I need to count, then, it's not like "+1 and/or -1" so I'm not sure it can be applied to both Article and Comment.

Any ideas on how could I design such system?

Btw, I'm using Doctrine 2 and Zend Framework.

Comment: I'd just add a column to each likable item in your table and give it a starting "like" score of `0`. Then just increment/decrement to your heart's content.

Comment: @Blender: You need to track who voted.

Comment: @Blender: I notice people on SO sometimes give answers in comments.  What's your thinking?  I'm just trying to adapt to SO culture.

Comment: @SLaks, then add a new column to each user and add the ID of the voted element. @k to the z, I do that because I have no experience with Zend or the alike.

Comment: @Blender: You need a separate table for that.

Comment: You couldn't just add that data to each item or to each user?

Comment: @Blender: No; you need a many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 3):

OK ... I think this won't be what you need, but here it goes ..

You should really watch this video : [Building Web Reputation Systems](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yn7e0J9m6rE)

About the issue: I think you shouldn't mix Articles and Comments in one big goo. They represent different types of entities.

I would create separate tables for both `CommentVotes` and `ArticleVotes`, and then have a row in both `Comments` and `Articles` called `total_likes` and for `Articles` additionally `total_dislikes` ( so that you don't have to recalculate the amount each time ).

Comment: +1, then add a method on the article and comment entities that calculate those values and sets them. Those methods can then be called from a @PostUpdate method on the comment entities. Then it's automated.

Comment: Hi, my ideas was to separate comment & article, and both commentVote & articleVote but with only one Vote entity

Comment: I guess this 'entity' concept is something that comes from your ORM. Because i don't see a point in mapping CommentVotes to any class in php. It is just another table which the Mapper for Comments object uses.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Doctrine but your database would look something like this:

```
article_votes(
    article_id, 
    user_id,
    score,
    primary key( article_id, user_id )
);
comment_votes(
    comment_id,
    user_id,
    primary key( comment_id, user_id )
);
```

For article_votes, score could be +1 for a like or -1 for a dislike. For comment_votes you could add a score column in case you wanted to allow for dislikes in the future. The primary key stops users from voting on an article or comment more than once. To get the total likes or dislikes you'd select count `WHERE score=1` or `WHERE score=-1`; to get the aggregate score of the article you'd select sum instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the system you described would work fine. When querying the databse you'll know what kind of entity youre trying to get info for so youll know which query to run.

**Votes Table**

5 is an article, 6 is a comment

```
id   user  parent  vote
3      3     5      1   vote
4      3     6     -1   dislike
5      4     6      1   like
```

to get votes for an article

```
select count(votes) from votes where parent=ARTICLE_ID
```

To get likes/dislikes on a comment

```
select (select count(vote) from votes where vote=-1 and parent=3) as dislikes, (select count(vote) from votes where vote=1 and parent=3) as likes
```